# How to get data when data were passing from old fragment to new fragment?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Old fragment.

```
lst.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    //var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(TracksByGenres));
    //intent.PutStringArrayListExtra ("keys",   items);
    //StartActivity (intent);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTx=this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    TracksByGenres fragTrack=new TracksByGenres();
    //get our item from listview
    fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer,fragTrack,items[e.Position]);      fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTx.Commit();
};
```

New fragment (fragTrack)

```
public async override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
    //What can I write? I want to get value from items[e.position] from old fragment
}
```

What's function to get value? I have search on google but there no results as I hope.

Comment: Do you want to pass data from while navigating to second fragment?

Comment: No. I don't want.
fragment1 will pass data to second fragment(I know how to write codes)
second Fragment will get this data. I want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your fragment to add a method which will accept data as below

This is your first fragment from where you take data.

```
   public class FirstFragment :Fragment {
 public string mData;
 public void AddData(string data) {
 mData=data; } 
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
// inflate layout and store in variable //you can use data here // myTextView.Text=mData; } }
```

This is the second fragment to where you send data

```
    public class SecondFragment :Fragment {
 public string mData;
 public void AddData(string data) {
 mData=data; } 
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
// inflate layout and store in variable //you can use data here // myTextView.Text=mData; } }
```

Now you can pass data while doing replace as below

```
SecondFragment aDifferentDetailsFrag = new SecondFragment(); 

aDifferentDetailsFrag.AddData(firstFragment.mData);
 //firstFragment is the instance of FirstFragment from where you are navigating to the secondfragment
// Replace the fragment that is in the View fragment_container (if applicable). 

fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag);
```

Comment: I mean how to get adifferentDetailsFrag in  new fragment

Comment: In new fragment, I want to get value of aDifferentDetailsFrag.

Comment: Navigation back from second Fragment to first fragment(navigation back on toolbar).??? MainActivity I have a button menu on toolbar.